# PHP: Adding tracks to spotify playlist with web-api - JSON ERROR

Tags: php, json, curl, spotify

I am trying to add a track to my own `playlist` with a little php script, but it won't work.

I always get the errror:

```
{ "error" : { "status" : 400, "message" : "Error parsing JSON." } }
```

This is the spotify document for adding tracks:
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/

Has anybody an idea what the problem could be?

```
$token='my Access token';

$headers = array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/*myusername*/playlists/*myplaylistID*/tracks' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'uris=spotify:track:3DXncPQOG4VBw3QHh3S817' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

print "$result";

$result = json_decode($result, true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: From a 2 minute read of the manual `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
'{"uris":"spotify:track:3DXncPQOG4VBw3QHh3S817"}' );`

Comment: Yeah, I saw this, but I a am new to json, what must I change in my code?

Comment: I changed it like you posted, it gave the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

I solved it finally:

```
$key='***AccessKey***';
```

$url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/***USERID***/playlists/***playlistID***/tracks?uris=spotify%3Atrack%3A3DXncPQOG4VBw3QHh3S817';

```
$headers = array(
        "Content-Length: 0",
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress",
        "User-Agent: runscope/0.1",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer ".$key);


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = array('uris' => 'spotify:track:3DXncPQOG4VBw3QHh3S817');
$data_json = json_encode($data);

// ...

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.spotify.com/...');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array
(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($data_json),
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
));  

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// ...
```